# Bitbucket pipelines, use ENV VARS in a NodeJS script to deploy to S3 Deploy

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, environment-variables, aws-sdk, bitbucket-pipelines

Right now I have a bitbucket pipeline that works well with a single step like so:
`( options: docker: true )`

```
- docker build --rm -f Dockerfile-deploy ./ -t deploy --build-arg AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --build-arg AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

This sets the keys in the Docker container, which then deploy's to an ELB using a bash script and the AWS-CLI to commit, so I don't actually try to expose the env vars, but `eb deploy` sure does and it works.

When trying to run a pipeline with the `image: node:latest` and the steps

```
- npm i
- npm run build ( Babel transpile )
- npm run deploy ( node script to send to S3 )
```

That final step I need the node script to have access to the env vars that I've added to the bitbucket repo pipelines config, instead I get a named variable representation of that variable:

```
// NodeJS Config File
module.exports = {
  AWS_S3_BUCKET              : process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET || undefined,
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY             : process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY || undefined,
  AWS_ACCESS_SECRET          : process.env.AWS_ACCESS_SECRET || undefined,
}
```

-

```
// NodeJS deploy file... parts
const aws = {
  params: {
    Bucket: config.AWS_S3_BUCKET
  },
  accessKeyId: config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: config.AWS_ACCESS_SECRET,
  distributionId: config.CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID,
  region: "us-east-1"
}
console.log('-----START AWS-----')
console.log(aws)
console.log('------END AWS------')
```

Then the bitbucket pipelines echo's this for the console.logs

```
-----START AWS-----
{ params: { Bucket: '$AWS_S3_BUCKET' },
  accessKeyId: '$AWS_ACCESS_KEY',
  secretAccessKey: '$AWS_ACCESS_SECRET',
  distributionId: '$CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID',
  region: 'us-east-1' }
------END AWS------
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well my problem was that I copy pasted the variables from AWS with a trailing space... which is a character, but certainly not in the expected secret or key string. Oops